# How to modify the query to exclude posts by slug?

Tags: query-posts, query

How can I modify my query in order to exclude certain posts by slug?
Is it possible?

```
query_posts(array('category_name' => 'Mycat', 'posts_per_page' => -1));
```

Ty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the post ID from the slug with the [`url_to_postid()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/url_to_postid) function:

```
$ID = url_to_postid(slug);
```

then just exclude the ID from your query:

```
query_posts(array('category_name' => 'Mycat', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'post__not_in' => $ID ));
```

You can create an array of post IDs if you need to exclude multiple pages.

Comment: Did not know about url_to_postid. Ty very much

Comment: Upvote for the `url_to_postid()` to get the post ID from the slug, but using `query_posts()` is the wrong implementation.

Comment: `post__not_in` in the above code should in fact be an array, so `$ID` needs to be in square brackets. `'post__not_in' => [$ID]`

Answer (score 5):

**Do not use `query_posts()`!**. Filter `pre_get_posts` instead *.

```
<?php
function wpse59617_filter_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
    // Only modify the main query
    if ( ! $query->is_main_query() ) { return $query; }
    // Get the ID of the post to exclude
    $slug = 'some-post-slug';
    $post_id = url_to_postid( $slug );
    // Modify the query
    $query->set( 'category_name', 'Mycat' );
    $query->set( 'post__not_in', $post_id );
    $query->set( 'posts_per_page', '-1' );
    // Return the modified query
    return $query;    
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse59617_filter_pre_get_posts' );
?>
```

* No, really: don't use `query_posts()`. [Here's why](http://www.slideshare.net/andrewnacin/you-dont-know-query-wordcamp-netherlands-2012).